# Propositional logic formula checking

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

I'm answering a question about propositional logic formulas, and was hoping one of you guys could check over my answer.

"Either the lift doors are open or the lift is moving and lift doors are closed"

Meanings:

$p$ "open"

$q$ "moving"

$r$ "closed"

My answer :

$(p \lor ( q \land r ))$

Sorry for not using the correct symbols, but I'm sure you'll understand what they're supposed to represent :P

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea, but let's nail down your propositions:

$p:$ The lift doors are open.

$q:$ The lift is moving.

$r:$ The lift doors are closed.

Then you're correct: The statement can be expressed logically as $$p \lor(q\land r)$$

Comment: Needs a TU -> +1